# Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeUsage does not contain a definition for GetUsages

Tags: content-type

I'm trying to carry out this example for deleting a content type in sharepoint: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttypeusage.aspx

but I'm getting the error mentioned in the title of this question on the following line:

```
IList<SPContentTypeUsage> usages = SPContentTypeUsage.GetUsages(obsolete);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not using the Client dll?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I faced the same issue within a Sandboxed solution. So looks like it is a limitation for sandbox solution.